# Net Core 5 project refuses to run

Tags: asp.net-core

I have gone through many sites figuring out how to prepare Net Core 5 project to run in IIS. I did publishing, I have downloaded all the needed pieces (or so I think) from here:
[Link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)

My web.config looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\RoundTheCode.ReactSignalR.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But when I run website like this:
http://localhost:8090/methodname I get:

[image]

Feels like I am still missing some parts of the framework. Can someone please explain what needs to be checked for that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the ASP.NET Core [Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) or is your app self-contained?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report to check common issues.

Comment: Yes, I did install the Bundle.

Comment: I installed  it from the provided link but not sure how to run my website inside of the tool. forgot to mention. It runs fine inside of VS2019

Comment: Ok, I ran the report and the only red text was this: Cannot locate executable: C:\ConvertHighchart\ConvertHighchart\%LAUNCHER_PATH%. What does that mean?

Comment: finally got it. I had to specify processPath="myexecutable". Thanks for the help!